# GitLab runner ignoring DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG when credential helper specified

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

We have a GitLab CI pipeline that currently pulls images from our internal Docker registry, authenticated using a variable defined in `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
variables:
  ...
  DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG: '{"auths": {"our.registry": {"auth": "$B64AUTH"}}}'
```

This works fine.

We are trying to add a step to the end of the pipeline, to push our built Docker images to an Amazon ECR registry. We have installed the amazon-ecr-credential-helper on our runner instances, and given them the correct IAM permissions to be able to push to these registries. We have changed the `.gitlab-ci.yml` variable to:

```
DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG: '{"auths": {"our.registry": {"auth": "$B64AUTH"}}, "credHelpers": { "<account-id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com": "ecr-login"}}'
```

However, this causes the runner to fail to authenticate to our internal registry, so it cannot pull the images in which our jobs run. Whereas previously we would see in our pipeline jobs' logs:

> Authenticating with credentials from $DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG

... we are no longer seeing this. We're not even getting to the step where we want to push to ECR.

We have added a wrapper script around the credential helper, to log all the ins and outs to a file, and try and debug what is happening. However, it appears as if the helper isn't getting called at all, as there is nothing in the log file.

What can we do to try and get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our problems here boiled down to a number of causes:

- Since we referenced the credential helper in `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG`, we needed the helper installed on the machine spawning the runners. (We use the `docker+machine` runner.) This machine also needed IAM permissions. Without this, it just gave up on the `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` variable completely (a questionable decision if you ask me...)
- In order to authenticate from within the jobs and push the images to ECR, we needed to configure the helper there too. We did this by modifying our spawner's `config.toml` file to add a volume `/usr/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login:/usr/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login`. (We also mounted the log directory and our helper wrapper.) In the `docker push` command, we added a `--config docker-config` flag, and wrote out an appropriate config to `docker-config.config.json`
- Finally, our job image was `docker/compose`, and our verbose wrapper was written in bash, which isn't included in that image, so that was another silent failure. .