# GitLab docker runner not setting DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG via config.toml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have an EC2 host with a role assigned to pull docker images. If I were to setup a `$HOME/.docker/config.json` with the content below I am able to successfully pull:

```
{ "credHelpers": {"XXXXXX.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com": "ecr-login" }}"
```

However, the GitLab runner fails with `no basic auth credentials` when attempting to pull the GitLab CI `services` image (hosted in ECR) which suggests to me that `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` is ignored.

The `config.toml` looks like this:

```
    [[runners]]
              name = "Global Share Runner"
              url = "gitlab.example.com"
              token = "xxxx"
              executor = "docker"
              environment = [
                "DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG={ \"credHelpers\": {\"XXXXXX.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com\": \"ecr-login\" }}"
              ]
```

I don't see the message `Authenticating with credentials from $DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` although when I turn on debugging via `CI_DEBUG_TRACE: true` I can see the value is set.

If however, I set the credentials helper (as shown above) in `/root/.docker/config.json` image pull works. It even logs `Authenticating with credentials from /root/.docker/config.json`.

I've reviewed the following questions and it doesn't quite answer the question I have:

- [Gitlab DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51814625/gitlab-docker-auth-config-not-working)
- [GitLab runner ignoring DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG when credential helper specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71394762/gitlab-runner-ignoring-docker-auth-config-when-credential-helper-specified)